# just wondering... Probability of Patriots winning

Tags: probability

Hypothetical Question:

Fact 1.)  Patriots win 90% of their games when played at Home.
Fact 2.)  Patriots win 80% of their games when Tom Brady plays.

What is the probability of the Patriots winning their game - if BOTH, the Patriots play at home AND Tom Brady plays?

i am mainly interested in how to calculate the probability of an event if you know 2 independent/different probabilities of that one event?

Comment: I guess you are asking it like this: $$P(win|TB)=0.8, P(win|Home)=0.9$$
What is $P(win|Home,TB)$? I thought this would be worth writing here.

Comment: Just a note - the probabilities aren't independent. Surely some of the games Tom played were played at home.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk Just the fact that some of the games Tom played were at home is not enough to determine dependence (or independence).  It matters how the joint probabilities are related.

Comment: Haha with or without cheating?